# LCD TV blinks when freezer blinks

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, freezing

My LCD TV, which I use as computer monitor, is connected to the same electric socket as the freezer (I do not have other sockets nearby). Whenever the freezer engine starts working, the TV blinks. This is uncomfortable, and I am also afraid that it may damage the screen.

Is this really dangerous for the screen?

What can I do to prevent it (other than installing another socket)?

Answer (score 1):

It could burn down your house. That shouldn't be a problem for good wiring, so I'd say you have a wiring problem to the outlet.  The momentary demand of the motor starting is making voltage drop enough to bother the TV. The voltage drop is making heat somewhere you don't want it.

Worst case, it's at the location of a wiring fault. There won't be enough heat for you to feel it on the outside of the wall, but potentially enough to kindle a fire if it's near anything flammable like dust bunnies.

Most likely it's one of the outlets.  Not necessarily this outlet, it could be another outlet upstream - outlets are daisy-chained. If you turn off the breaker to that outlet, check what other outlets have also gone out.  That will show you the "daisy chain" that is involved.  (it goes without saying to shutdown your PCs before you start shutting off breakers.)

Can you borrow a socket checker and a Kill-a-Watt and look for anything funny electrically?  Once you've identified the daisy-chain of outlets, a significantly different voltage from one outlet to the next (while the freezer is running) would mean you're close to the problem.

Outlets are $4 for a good one (58 cents for a cheapie) and it's a reasonably easy DIY project if you school up and are careful.  Food for thought.

Comment: I used a socket-checker. The sockets in the wall are OK (green light), but, I have a multi-socket connected to one of the wall-sockets, and in it, two of the four sockets were not OK (red light). So, I put the freezer in one of the good sockets and the screen in the other good socket, but... the problem remains. I will try to get a kill-a-watt as you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this necessarily indicates a problem with your electrical, but it's possible.  It could be that the voltage on the circuit is lower than it should be, the wiring could be undersized, bad receptacle, etc.  It could be that the refrigerator's compressor motor is drawing more than it should at start and causing more voltage drop than it should.  It's also possible that the monitor is just very sensitive to normal voltage drop and even though everything else is within spec it's going to flicker.

If you don't have another receptacle available, you could use an uninterruptible power supply (UPS) - a battery backup for your computer and monitor.  However, it's possible that some UPS's won't help - a *line interactive* UPS might not help, an *online* UPS should.  It's also possible that a different monitor may be less sensitive to the voltage drop when the refrigerator starts up.